Некорректное закрытие скобок Опенаи аиограм
async def send_message_with_retry(bot, chat_id, text, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN):
    max_retries = 5
    for attempt in range(1, max_retries + 1):
        try:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, text, parse_mode=parse_mode)
            return True
        except TelegramAPIError as e:
            logging.warning(f"Ошибка Telegram API (попытка {attempt}/{max_retries}): {e}. Повторяем...")
            await asyncio.sleep(attempt * 2)  # Экспоненциальный backoff
    logging.error(f"Не удалось отправить сообщение после нескольких попыток: {text}")
    return False

def split_response(response, max_length=3000):
    parts = []
    current_part = ""
    in_code_block = False
    code_block_start = -1 # Запоминаем позицию начала блока кода

    for i, char in enumerate(response):
        current_part += char

        if char == '///' and i + 2 < len(response) and response[i+1] == '///' and response[i+2] == '///':
            if in_code_block:
                # Закрытие блока кода
                in_code_block = False
                code_block_length = i - code_block_start + 3 # Длина блока кода, включая маркеры
                if code_block_length > max_length:
                    # Разделение блока кода, если он слишком большой
                    parts.append(current_part)
                    current_part = "" # Начало новой части
            else:
                # Открытие блока кода
                in_code_block = True
                code_block_start = i

        elif len(current_part) > max_length and not in_code_block:
            # Разбиение вне блока кода
            parts.append(current_part)
            current_part = ""

        elif len(current_part) > max_length and in_code_block:
            # Разбиение внутри блока кода
            parts.append(current_part[:max_length]) #Добавлена обработка разбиения внутри блока кода
            current_part = current_part[max_length:] # Остаток блока кода в начало новой части
            
    if current_part:
        parts.append(current_part)

    return parts
    
    
async def generate_response(user_id, user_message, bot: Bot):
    try:
        await start_typing(bot, user_id)
        model_name = await get_user_model(user_id)
        context = await get_context(user_id)
        context.insert(0, {"role": "system", "content": system_prompt})
        context.append({"role": "user", "content": user_message})

        base_url, api_key = get_api_credentials(model_name) # Функция получения параметров
        if not base_url or not api_key:
            await send_message_with_retry(bot, user_id, f"Ошибка: Неизвестная модель '{model_name}'", parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
            return

        client = OpenAI(api_key=api_key, base_url=base_url)  # Создаем клиента после определения параметров
        response = client.chat.completions.create(model=model_name, messages=context, temperature=0.5)
        logging.info(f"Ответ OpenAI: {response}")  # Залогируйте весь объект ответа         logging.info(f"Варианты ответа OpenAI: {response.choices}")
        logging.info(f"Содержание ответа OpenAI: {response.choices[0].message.content}")
        response_message = response.choices[0].message.content
        print(f"Ответ нейросети(no-format): {response_message}")
        # Санитация Markdown (удаление тегов)
        response_message = re.sub(r'<[^>]+>', '', response_message)  # Удаляет все HTML-теги
        response_message = response_message.strip()
        print(f"Ответ нейросети(format): {response_message}")
        MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 4096 # Максимальная длина сообщения Telegram
        response_parts = split_response(response_message, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH)  # Разбиваем сообщение

        for part in response_parts:
            await send_message_with_retry(bot, user_id, part, parse_mode="Markdown")  # Отправляем каждую часть

        await stop_typing(bot, user_id)
        await save_message(user_id, "user", user_message)
        await save_message(user_id, "assistant", response_message)
        return response_message

    except OpenAIError as openai_error:
        await stop_typing(bot, user_id)
        logging.exception(f"Ошибка OpenAI API: {openai_error}")
        await send_message_with_retry(bot, user_id, f"‼️Произошла ошибка\n{openai_error}\nна стороне нашего провайдера. \n️Возможно он уже чинит сервера. \nПопробуйте позже.", parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)

    except Exception as e:
        await stop_typing(bot, user_id)
        logging.exception(f"Ошибка при генерации ответа: {e}")
        await send_message_with_retry(bot, user_id, "Произошла неизвестная ошибка. Попробуйте позже.", parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)

Вроде как скобки некорректно закрывается , потому что возникает ошибка Bad Requests: can't find end of entity (byte offset...) но длинные ответы без кода бот отправляет и они разбиваются на части. Вообще мне нужно чтобы было так:
(Текст ///\nИмя языка\nкод/// | ///\nИмя языка\nкод/// текст)

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
